# Instance Differents AWS Buckets using aws-sdk-react-native

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

I have two different buckets in S3 (with their respectives ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, so I need instance them in a same function. Currently I have a function in order to instance the current Bucket (depending of environment), as follow

```
import S3 from "aws-sdk/clients/s3";
import { S3_BUCKET, S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, S3_ACCESS_KEY } from 'react-native-dotenv' 

const getSignedURL = key => {
    s3I = new AWS.S3({
        accessKeyId: S3_ACCESS_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET
    })
    return key !== undefined && key !== '' && key !== null
        ? s3I.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
            Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
            Key: key
        })
        : ''
}

export default {
  getSignedURL
};
```

And works very well, but only retrieve the images for the current bucket (i.e. develop).

How can I instance both?

Thanks

**POST DATA**
I've tried using OR in the S3 Object but didn't work (only retrieved the first):

```
s3I = new AWS.S3({
        accessKeyId: S3_ACCESS_KEY_PROD || S3_ACCESS_KEY_DEV,
        secretAccessKey: S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_PROD || S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DEV,
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET_PROD || S3_BUCKET_DEV
    })
```

**POST DATA 2**
Also I've tried as follow, without success:

```
const getSignedURL = key => {
    s3IProd = new AWS.S3({
        accessKeyId: S3_ACCESS_KEY_PROD,
        secretAccessKey: S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_PROD,
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET_PROD
    })
    s3IDev = new AWS.S3({
      accessKeyId: S3_ACCESS_KEY_DEV,
      secretAccessKey: S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DEV,
      Bucket: S3_BUCKET_DEV
  })
    return key !== undefined && key !== '' && key !== null
        ? s3IProd.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
            Bucket: S3_BUCKET_PROD,
            Key: key
        }) && s3IDev.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
          Bucket: S3_BUCKET_DEV,
          Key: key
        })
        : ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly have two separate functions for both environments. Eg `getSignedURLDev()` and `getSignedProd()`. Ideally, you should only need to pass in the secret keys for the specific environment you're in using `process.env`. Since this is react native you might need to use the `babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables` package for that.

Comment: I've tried that too, but didn't work. I.E.: when I define an object instancing the functions, only retrieves the first ```photo: getSignedURLDev(photoKey) || getSignedURLProd(photoKey)```. But, if the photo is in the second bucket doesn't show.